# Spring-Boot Thymeleaf Load image in html-form with list doesnt display

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

i'm making little app with uploading menu (image) using Spring-Boot Thymeleaf my upload menu is working so either list menu uploading , but the problem is when i try to display my image from static folder in netbeans to webpage just my filename is show up but my image didnt.   how should it be ?

i get filedata image from listmenu that i was created before.

//this is from my list.html:

```
<table border='1' width='50%' height='100%'>
        <tr th:each="files: ${fileName}">
        <td th:text="${files}"/>
        <td><img src="../static/img/ "width="100"
         th:src="@{img/' + files + '}"/></td>

        </tr>
```

i expect the ouput at webpage is my filename(from image) and image show up.

Answer (score 0):

Your th:src seams to be wrong. It should be

```
<img th:src="@{'/img/'+ ${files}}">
```

Comment: ty you for respond my question sir,
i've tried but still didnt work.
this is my generate html :
`<div>list :</div>
        <table border='1' width='50%' height='50%'>
            <tr>
            <td>bunga.jpg</td>
            <td><img src="/img/${files}"/></td>                  
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>cropped-1920-1080-40227.jpg</td>
            <td><img src="/img/${files}"/></td>                  
            </tr>
            <tr>`

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake. Please check the updated answer

Comment: done sir, this is should be..
 `<td><img src="../img/" width="500px" 
                    th:src="@{${'img/' + files + ''}}"/></td>`
my img and my name files is show up.
ty for ur kind respon.